# Expressão equivalente a "with a grain of salt"

Tags: expressões, tradução-inglês, expressões-idiomáticas

Qual seria uma forma equivalente de se dizer em português *"take [this] with a grain of salt"*? O significado dessa expressão em inglês é algo tipo não tomar o que foi dito como verdade absoluta, usar o senso crítico, algo assim (no meu entendimento, posso estar enganado quanto ao significado exato).

[Aqui tem mais informações](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+with+a+grain+of+salt) sobre essa expressão idiomática, e um exemplo:

> *I've read the article, which I take with a grain of salt.*

Como eu poderia expressar isso em português de uma forma que tivesse o mesmo significado e fosse compreensível?

**Atualização:** não sei se o sentido da expressão original ficou claro, mas vou tentar explicar exatamente como eu entendo *"with a grain of salt"* e por que não estou 100% satisfeito com as respostas sugeridas:

Às vezes escrevemos algo tentando ser o mais correto e imparcial possível, mas temos consciência de que nosso conhecimento é limitado e - por ser um assunto sobre o qual temos opinião forte e/ou mexe com nossos sentimentos, acabamos por escrever segundo um ponto de vista muito particular que pode não corresponder à forma que a maioria das pessoas pensa. Queremos deixar claro pro leitor que estamos cientes das nossa limitações (nem que seja pra evitar bate-boca nos comentários, quando aplicável). Entretanto:

1. Nada foi dito figurativamente ou metaforicamente, foi tudo literal. Então é sim pra "levar ao pé da letra";
2. Nada foi dito com malícia, segundas intenções ou de forma enganadora, estou sendo sincero. Não é necessário ficar "com um pé atrás".

Dessa forma, a expressão sugere que o leitor tenha senso crítico, use o bom senso, considere pontos de vista diferentes, seja cético, etc. Me pergunto se há algo simples em português que expresse bem esse sentido. A propósito, a expressão *"your mileage may vary"* (YMMV) tem certa relação com esse conceito (também significando que a "verdade" do que foi dito depende também do ponto de vista).

Aqui estão [mais](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/take-with-a-grain-of-salt.html) [duas](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=with%20a%20grain%20of%20salt) definições da expressão em inglês, também seguindo a mesma linha.

Comment: Não expressa exatamente o mesmo significado, mas em certos casos dá pra usar "com um pé atrás".

Comment: @bfavaretto Até o momento essa expressão foi a que chegou mais perto da ideia que eu queria passar (ainda não está lá, entretanto), não quer postar como resposta?

Comment: Não coloco como resposta porque tenho, ainda, esperanças de achar uma expressão melhor em português.

Comment: Seria algo na linha de "relativizar", "relativizando". Sem "pé", que curiosamente aparece tanto na minha sugestão quanto na do Luiz :P

Comment: Evite o senso comum.

Comment: Estou vendo essa pergunta hoje pela primeira vez e concordo com o/a @bfavaretto.  O que me veio a mente imediatamente foi "com um pé atrás" e, a mim, parece servir melhor do que as outras opções apresentadas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma expressão idiomática que pode ser usada com um sentido similar (de que algo falado não deve ser considerado necessariamente verdadeiro) é "ao pé da letra". Ela tem em português o sentido de "literalmente". Assim você pode usar para dizer, por exemplo:

> Ele disse que depois vem te dar um tapa. Mas ele estava brincando, não leve ao pé da letra.

Como eu mencionei em comentários, uma alternativa é a expressão "a ferro-e-fogo". Ela talvez tenha um sentido mais próximo do que você deseja (pois dizer pra "não levar algo a ferro-e-fogo" é dizer para não tomar esse algo como uma verdade absoluta, ou um fato imutável). Mas ainda assim eu acho (é só uma opinião baseada em o que eu vejo as pessoas utilizarem) que "não leve ao ao pé da letra" é mais popular também nesse uso (de refutar algo como verdade absoluta).

Comment: Eu estou aqui pensando se aceito essa resposta ou não, mas ainda não estou satisfeito: "não levar ao pé da letra", na minha cabeça significa que algo foi dito metaforicamente/figurativamente (já que seria o oposto de "literalmente"), quando na verdade a ideia que eu quero expressar é outra. Por exemplo, eu posso dizer uma coisa da forma mais correta e imparcial possível, mas sempre vou acabar emitindo alguma opinião e/ou cometer erros por falta de conhecimento, mas tudo o que eu disse foi literal (não metafórico).

Comment: Sim, você tem razão. É muito mais sobre algo metafórico. Mas, eu acho que é a expressão mais próxima em português. Você poderia dizer "não tome isso como uma verdade absoluta", mas ai você está literalmente dizendo o que quer, sem usar uma expressão (que, em si, também é uma metáfora tal qual "a grain of salt"). Outras expressões metafórias poderiam ser "não leve isso a ferro-e-fogo" ou mesmo "não entenda tudo tão literalmente" (como você mesmo propõe, no final das contas).

Comment: Entretanto, explicando a sua questão para outras pessoas a primeira expressão que vem na cabeça delas (ao menos com quem eu falei) é justamente "ao pé da letra". Acho que é um abuso aceitável. :) De todas as formas, sugiro que não escolha uma resposta como aceita (deixe a questão aberta). Vai que aparecem outras pessoas com ideias melhores...

Comment: Ei, "levar a ferro-e-fogo" me parece uma boa alternativa! Ainda que o significado não seja 100% equivalente (na realidade, não consegui encontrar uma definição satisfatória dessa expressão), ela expressa uma posição absolutista, às últimas consequências, etc, que é justamente o contrário do que eu quero expressar (ser flexível, considerar outros pontos de vista, etc). De modo que dizer "não leve a ferro-e-fogo" transmite a mensagem certa, por assim dizer. Eu poderia aceitar isso (mesmo dando abertura pro caso de no futuro alguém aparecer com uma expressão melhor).

Comment: Bom, eu editei para incluir essa sugestão. :)

Comment: Não confunda alhos com bugalhos.

Answer (score 7):

Bem, se fosse eu, optaria por algo assim:

'' entenda-se, sempre com as  devidas ressalvas, e salvo melhor e douta análise que (...) ''

Pelo menos no sentido em que a queres colocar, talvez assim se aproxime do que queres salvaguardar. Porque à letra, não seria bem assim, claro.

Answer (score 7):

Em Portugal, mas parece-me que não no Brasil, usa-se a expressão **vale o que vale**, que quando aplicada a declarações, significa que estas podem não valer muito, que não têm que ser ou não devem ser tomadas como 100% verdade. O exemplo da pergunta ficaria assim em Português:

> I've read the article, which I take with a grain of salt.
>
> Li o artigo, e acho que aquilo vale o que vale.

Aqui estão alguns exemplos reais da net com o link e tradução parcial:

> [De facto, na sociedade actual](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205044507/http://www.gifi.pt/portal/programs/ewpview.aspx?codigo=MANIFESTO) a ciência desempenha um papel de relevo, funcionando muitas vezes como o garante da veracidade de determinados acontecimentos e fenómenos. No entanto, devemos ser críticos relativamente a essa tendência natural. Uma explicação científica **vale o que vale**, no contexto em que é dada. (A scientific expanation must be understood with a grain of salt, in the context where it is put forth.)
>
> [[A propósito de um ranking onde Hazard vale mais que Ronaldo]](https://visaodemercado.blogspot.pt/2015/06/defesa-do-chelsea-deu-nega-ao-real.html) Qualquer equipa que tivesse a certez que por 150 ME garantia ou Hazard ou Ronaldo certamente optaria pelo português pelo mediatismo da transferência e valor que acrescentaria à sua equipa em marketing, portanto toda a gente sabe que este ranking **vale o que vale**... (everybody knows this ranking is to be taken with a grain of salt.)
>
> [O presidente do Benfica](https://euvistodevermelhoebranco.blogs.sapo.pt/tempo-para-reflectir-7895) ter-lhe-á oferecido as mesmas condições contratuais, mas o treinador preferiu dar novo rumo à sua carreira. A história das exigências dos jogadores da formação e de um máximo de 25 jogadores no plantel que tinham sido exigidas a Jorge Jesus, foram desmentidas pelo próprio, e isso **vale o que vale**. (...were denied by himself, and the denial is to be taken with a grain of salt.)

A expressão é também muito usada exatamente com o mesmo sentido, mas como expressão de modéstia:

> [É apenas a minha opinião](https://vale-o-que-vale.blogspot.pt/) e **vale o que vale**. Para mim vale muito, para os outros pode não valer nada. E com isso posso eu bem. (It's only my opinion, take it with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Precisamos urgentemente importar essa expressão para o Brasil!

Comment: Tenho a certeza que a encontrei num site brasileiro, mas com outro sentido, [que vale muito, como também se encontra em Portugal](http://oindefectivel.blogspot.pt/2015/09/gaitan-vale-o-que-vale.html)

Comment: E o mais engraçado, é que _vale o que vale_ é tautológico: só por si não significa nada, mas toda a gente sabe o que significa.

Answer (score 6):

Pode-se usar a expressão latina, [*cum grano salis*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/cum_grano_salis) de PT.Wiktionary:

> 1. com ponderação, com parcimônia
> 2. com uma pitada de sal
> 3. com graça
> 4. chistoso